# ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). When using "multipart/form-data"

Tags: apache, http-status-code-403, mod-security, mod-security2

I am trying to upload image to web server. And receive Error:403. So I check the Apache log, I have this error in log:

```
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Match of "eq 0" against "MULTIPART_STRICT_ERROR" required. [file "/usr/local/cwaf/rules/13_HTTP_Protocol.conf"] [line "30"] [id "210240"] [rev "4"] [msg "COMODO WAF: Multipart request body failed strict validation: PE 0, BQ 1, BW 0, DB 0, DA 0, HF 0, LF 0, SM , IQ 0, IH 0, FLE 0||my_web_server.com|F|2"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "CWAF"] [tag "Protocol"] [hostname "my_web_server.com"] [uri "/projects/BoLe/api/saveimage.php"] [unique_id "XDaxYXuIw@DonQukuLB6swAAAAs"]
```

According to [this site](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#MULTIPART_STRICT_ERROR) my requests have `MULTIPART_BOUNDARY_QUOTED` error and I tried to Google it and I still  don't understand what is happening. Therefore I used `wireshark` to check the packet

```
|%ÝrÜðÕ¿wëE%6@QÔ¬[ggféP3)¯W^P@)îù
POST /projects/BoLe/api/saveimage.php HTTP/1.1
Host: massmodules.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, identity
Connection: Keep-Alive, TE
User-Agent: BestHTTP
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="8A317780"
Content-Length: 306

|%ÝrÜðÕ¿wëEZ%7@Q¬[ggféP3)°@^P@)õ`--8A317780
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileName"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length: 17

i_am_fileName.png
--8A317780
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileName2"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length: 18

i_am_fileName2.png
--8A317780--
```

Could someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: It's the quote signs in the content-type header. It should be 
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=8A317780, solution depends on the way the request is generated.

Comment: It can also be reported when the webserver uid doesn't have write permission to SecUploadDir/SecTmpDir/SecDataDir . OP: If your only recourse for resolving these issues is to post here, you maybe shouldn't be using mod_security.

Comment: @sui this work thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule that triggered the error is this one:

```
BQ %{MULTIPART_BOUNDARY_QUOTED}, \
```

This is visible in the error message:

```
PE 0, BQ 1, BW 0, DB 0, DA 0, HF 0, LF 0, SM , IQ 0, IH 0, FLE 0
      ⬆⬆⬆⬆
```

The issue is that you have quotes in the content-type header

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
                                  ⬆     ⬆
```

Comment: really thanks.you saved me from a hell error.